# How do I combine wxPython, abc, and a metaclass mixin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, abc

I have a base class from which other classes should inherit:

```
class AppToolbar(wx.ToolBar):
    ''' Base class for the Canary toolbars '''

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ... a few common implementation details that work as expected...

        self._PopulateToolbar()
        self.Realize()
```

The base class does not (and cannot) implement `_PopulateToolbar()`; it should be an abstract method. As such, I figured using `abc` was a good plan, so I tried this:

```
class AppToolbar(wx.ToolBar, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
     # ... as above, but with the following added
     @abc.abstractmethod
     def _PopulateToolbar():
         pass
```

Perhaps unsurprisingly, attempting to run this led to `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`. I thought, "Oh, right, I'll just use a mixin":

```
class PopulateToolbarMixin(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def _PopulateToolbar(self):
        pass

PopulateToolbarMixin.register(wx.ToolBar)
PopulateToolbarMixin.register(AppToolbar)
```

No change: still the same `TypeError` message. I suspect I'm missing something obvious with the use of `ABCMeta` here; this doesn't look like an error specific to wxPython. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to approach the same issue?

**Edit:** it has been pointed out to me in a conversation with a colleague that one cannot mix metaclasses. Since `wx.ToolBar` apparently derives from `sip.wrappertype`, it looks like there is no way to do this. What is another, still Pythonic way to handle the "abstract method" approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, where you inherit from wx.ToolBar and abc.ABCMeta, you don't want AppToolbar to be a *subclass* of abc.ABCMeta, you want AppToolbar to be an *instance* of it. Try this:

```
class AppToolbar(wx.ToolBar, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
     # ... as above, but with the following added
     @abc.abstractmethod
     def _PopulateToolbar():
         pass
```

Though looking at this a bit closer, it seems that you can't define a subclass of wx.Toolbar with abc.ABCMeta as its metaclass, as wx.Toolbar is an instance of a metaclass other than bultins.type. You can, however, get abstract-like behavior out of AppToolbar._PopulateToolbar:

```
class AppToolbar(wx.ToolBar):
     def _PopulateToolbar():
         ''' This is an abstract method; subclasses must override it. '''

         raise NotImplementedError('Abstract method "_PopulateToolbar" must be overridden before it can be called.')
```

Comment: Mmm, good catch; that's actually what I originally had (forgot it when re-creating the code here). Alas, there's some kind of odd conflict with wxPython specifically, it seems, as this doesn't work.

Comment: Then it would seem that wx.ToolBar is not a direct instance of type, in which case you're out of luck; as far as I know, there isn't a good way to combine metaclasses in Python.